OpenCV contours sorting x-axis and y-axis
I am working on a python program to solve a wordsearch.  I am using pytesseract and opencv to process an image of the wordsearch and the solution will be displayed as a text.  The script processes the image to improve accuracy of contouring and eventually performing OCR.  The challenge I am running into is the sorting of the contours.  I have attached a processed image and my script as well as the original wordsearch test image.  I am expecting the results to be sequential which is critical to solve the wordsearch.  I am finding the numbers are not sequential.
Processed Image If you look at the first row of the image above, you will notice that while the script identifies majority of the characters, the sequence is incorrect.  For the first 5 characters, I am expecting to process as B A J L A, but the processes is B A J A L and this continues further in the row. I have not been able to figure out a pattern at which this happens.
Starting Image
The image above is what I am using for testing.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract

def process_grid(filename):
    img = cv2.imread(filename)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.
THRESH_OTSU)[1]

    items = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = items[0] if len(items) == 2 else items[1]

    img_contour = img.copy()

    bounding_boxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in contours]
    contours, bounding_boxes = zip(*sorted(zip(contours, bounding_boxes), 
key=lambda b: (b[1][1], b[1][0])))
    detected = ""
    counter = 0
    success = 0
    failed = 0
    img_cropped = ""
    detected = ""
    for c in contours:
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ratio = h/w
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        base = np.ones(thresh.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
        if ratio > 0.1 and 100 < area < 10000:
            base[y:y+h, x:x+w] = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            segment = cv2.bitwise_not(base)
            custom_config = r'-l eng --oem 3 --psm 10 -c 
tessedit_char_whitelist="ABCDEFGHIlJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" '
            identified = pytesseract.image_to_string(segment, 
config=custom_config)
            counter = counter + 1
            detected = detected + identified 
            img_cropped = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            print(f'counter: {counter} - char: {identified.strip()}')
            if len(identified.strip()) > 0:
                temp_text = str(counter) + " - " + identified.strip()
                cv2.rectangle(img_contour, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
                tracker = cv2.putText(img_contour, temp_text, (x+w, y+h-10), 
cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0), 1)
                success = success + 1
            else:
                temp_text = str(counter) + " - " 
                cv2.rectangle(img_contour, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
                tracker = cv2.putText(img_contour, temp_text, (x+w, y+h-10),
                        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (0, 0, 225), 1)
                failed = failed + 1

    print("Counter: " + str(counter))
    print("Success: " + str(success))
    print("Failed: " + str(failed))
    
    cv2.imwrite("tracker.jpeg", tracker)


process_grid("IMG_2878.JPG")

I have tried various approaches mostly using chatGPT to figure out different approaches to sorting. Also tried figuring out changing the different configuration for opencv.findcontours but I found both RETR_EXTERNAL and CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE are currently providing better results.
Hoping for input/guidance on improving the sorting of the contours to be sequential.

Yes, contours are not detected sequentially. Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66946804/python-sorting-items-from-top-left-to-bottom-right-with-opencv

there have been questions like this. general approach: sort into rows, then sort each row. -- [mre] required. does this step involve OCR, or does it not? -- code needs refactoring. one function doing everything is not as easy to read as a few functions with defined purposes.
