# How to find the center point of two objects in a binary image with openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

I need to get the coordinates (center points) of the two white objects in my binary image for further processing. This is an example image:
[image]
How can I achieve this?
I am using Python and openCV

Comment: Find contours `->` Find centroids

Comment: what did you try to solve your problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582008/center-of-mass-in-contour-python-opencv

Answer (score 0):

It is not opencv, but you can give a try to the `regionprops` method of skimage [example from the docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-label-py)

```
from skimage.measure import regionprops


for region in regionprops(yourbinary_image):
    centroid = region.centroid
    #do stuff with that centroid ;)
```